# Ruby << (double less than) with instance variables

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure how this is valid code:

```
class Library
  def initialize(games)
    @games = games
  end

  def add_game(game)
    games << game
  end

  def games()
    @games
  end
end

games = ['WoW','SC2','D3']
lib = Library.new(games)
puts lib.games
lib.add_game('Titan')
puts lib.games
```

This will print out:

WoW
SC2
D3
Titan

I would think that it should print out

WoW
SC2
D3

The add_game method doesn't use the instance variable.  Being new to Ruby, I don't understand how this works.  Shouldn't it have to be:

```
def add_games(game)
  @games << game
end
```

I'm reading this from a tutorial and I haven't been able to find anything on how << works specifically with instance variables.  I thought '<<' was just overloaded when dealing with arrays to be 'append to the array'.  Is this actually doing something w/ Singleton classes?

Comment: As an aside, try adding a `puts games` after your last `puts lib.games` and you'll see why `@games = games` should be `@games = games.dup`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is a little confusing.  The line:

```
games << game
```

is actually calling the method `games`, which returns `@games`.  Then the `<<` method is called on that result.  There's some syntactic sugar in the Ruby parser that turns the `<<` operator into a method call on the left operand, and the left operand is being evaluated before that happens.

**Edit for more clarity:**

The line could be written like this:

```
(games).<< game
```

or this:

```
(self.games).<< game
```

or:

```
(self.games) << game
```

all of which execute the `games` method.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense Jim.  Thank you!

Comment: Or `games() << game` which would have been self-documenting and probably avoid the confusion in the first place.

Comment: without the parents it is much more DSL-ish, and encapsulate-y, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It uses class instance variable, look at your code :

```
class Library
  def initialize(manygames)
    @games = manygames
  end

  def add_game(game)
    imlookingforclassinstancevariable << game
  end

  def imlookingforclassinstancevariable
    @games #i'm the final storage of your array
  end
end
games = ['WoW','SC2','D3']
lib = Library.new(games)
puts lib.imlookingforclassinstancevariable
lib.add_game('Titan')
puts lib.imlookingforclassinstancevariable
```

Comment: Why "class instance variable" as opposed to just "instance variable"?